# How change the default mapping strategy (BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping) to another as SimpleUrlHandlerMapping through defaultHandler property?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` is the default mapping strategy and is used if no other mapping strategies are defined in the ApplicationContext. My question is simple:

**How can we change this default mapping strategy to SimpleUrlHandlerMapping for instance through defaultHandler property?**

Can we change it with this configuration below :

```
<bean id="simpleHander" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <value>
            /student/test=testController
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultHandler" ref="simpleHandler">
</bean>

<bean id="testController" class="com.test.controller.TestController"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A web application can define any number of DispatcherServlets. Each servlet will operate in its own namespace, loading its own application context with mappings, handlers, etc. Only the root application context as loaded by ContextLoaderListener, if any, will be shared.

A dispatcher servlet can be configured only one implementation of [HandlerMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html).
From spring documentation

> DispatcherServlet can use any HandlerMapping implementation - pre-built or provided as part of an application - to control the routing of requests to handler objects. Default is BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping and RequestMappingHandlerMapping. HandlerMapping objects can be defined as beans in the servlet's application context, implementing the HandlerMapping interface, overriding the default HandlerMapping if present. HandlerMappings can be given any bean name (they are tested by type).

#### 1. How to configure SimpleUrlHandlerMapping

Configuring SimpleUrlHandlerMapping means configuring dispatcher servlet to use SimpleUrlHandlerMapping as HandlerMapping. It can be done in your dispatcher servlet configuration xml file. So first configure your dispatcher servlet to use a xml file for initializing.
**In your web.xml**

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>simpleUrlHandlerDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/simpleUrlHandlerMapping.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>simpleUrlHandlerDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.simple</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**In Your simpleUrlHandlerMapping.xml**

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/hello.simple">simpleHello</prop>
            <prop key="/hi.simple">simpleHi</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="simpleHello" class="com.pvn.HelloController" />
<bean name="simpleHi" class="com.pvn.HiController" />
```

#### 2. Alternatives of injecting values for mappings property in SimpleUrlHandlerMapping

As `mappings` property need `java.util.Properties` We can use any of the below

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/hello.simple">simpleHello</prop>
            <prop key="/hi.simple">simpleHi</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <value>
            /hello.simple=simpleHello 
            /hi.simple=simpleHi
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <util:properties  location="classpath:url-mappings.properties">
        </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean>
```

For last method, you need to create properties file in classpath as given below
[image]

And also you need to add XSD for your xml to avail `<util:properties>` tag.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
```